# How to find my Office for Mac key within the program?

Tags: hard-drive, ms-office

I just removed my CD Optical drive from my Macbook Pro 2009 and replaced it with an SSD. I cloned my original drive using disk utility and now boot to the SSD. Everything transfered well except for Office. It now asks me to input my key again. Unfortunately I do not have the original key as I purchased the MBP from someone else. Is there a way to find the key within Office on the old hard drive?

Comment: The bad news, MS does not allow that. The Good news, MS is very helpful if you call them and ask for new activation key.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD but would the solution proposed in the previous comment from grgarside work?

Comment: You can try to copy the said plist from the old drive to the new one no harm in that. AFIK - MS has made that the drive dependent so it might not work.

Comment: Alright then I'll give that a shot later and update whether or not it works. Thanks! @Buscar웃SD

Comment: read this for more help http://www.officeformachelp.com/2014/01/microsoft-office-activation-faqs/